# Cómo puedo hacer un SortedMap con clave String y valor los n Integer más altos de una lista

Tags: java, lista, ordenamiento, map, stream

Quiero hacer un SortedMap cuya clave sea un equipo de fútbol y su valor una lista de los n partidos de visitante que más goles metieron, pero mostrando solo el número de goles.
Tengo un csv con los datos, getVisitante serían los equipos y getGolesVisitante los goles en cada partido.

La respuesta que busco sería algo así:
{Arsenal: [7,4,3], Man United: [6,5,4],...}

Aquí he hecho un método que da el resultado que quiero, pero necesito que sea un SotedMap, no un Map.

```
private List<Integer> listaPartidosOrdenadosPorGoles(List<PremierLeague> a) {
        return a.stream()
                .sorted((a1,b)->b.getGolesVisitante().compareTo(a1.getGolesVisitante()))
                .map(p -> p.getGolesVisitante())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
public Map<String, Object> visitanteGoleador(Integer n) {
    return partidos.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PremierLeague::getVisitante, 
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), g -> listaPartidosOrdenadosPorGoles(g).subList(0, n))));
    }
```

Código PremierLeague:

```
public class PremierLeague implements Comparable<PremierLeague> {
    private String visitante;
    private Integer golesVisitante;

    public PremierLeague(String visitante, Integer golesVisitante) {    
        if (golesVisitante < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No hay goles negativos");
        }
        this.visitante = visitante;
        this.golesVisitante = golesVisitante;
    }
    public String getVisitante() {
        return visitante;
    }

    public void setVisitante(String visitante) {
        this.visitante = visitante;
    }
    public Integer getGolesVisitante() {
        return golesVisitante;
    }

    public void setGolesVisitante(Integer golesVisitante) {
        this.golesVisitante = golesVisitante;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "visitante=" + visitante + ", golesVisitante=" + 
                golesVisitante;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(PremierLeague o) {
        int res = this.getVisitante().compareTo(o.getVisitante());
        return res;
    }
}
```

Esto junto a sus equals, hashCode.

Los datos del csv vendrían de la siguiente forma:
[visitante=Arsenal, golesVisitante=3],[visitante=Arsenal, golesVisitante=4],[visitante=Arsenal, golesVisitante=0],[visitante=Arsenal, golesVisitante=1],
[visitante=Man United, golesVisitante=5],[visitante=Man United, golesVisitante=1],[visitante=Man United, golesVisitante=2],[visitante=Man United, golesVisitante=3]

Comment: puedes poner el codigo de PremierLeague? siempre trata de tener poner un [mcve]

Comment: @RuslanLópez he mejorado el código. Espero que se vea mejor. No me cabe el código PremierLeague, es la clase donde están los atributos (entre ellos golesVisitante y visitante) con dos constructores, compareTo, hashCode, toString, equals, los getter y setter

Comment: No necesitas ponernos todo, @Javi. Como bien ha dicho Ruslan, necesitas darnos un [MRE] para poder compilar tu código y probar cosas. Nuestra cabeza no compila java al fin y al cabo :) En vez de poner **todo** el código de tu clase, danos una versión simplificada! Tan solo usas el atributo `golesVisitante`, pues pon una clase con únicamente ese atributo y listo! Si no, para poder probar nos obligas a hacer eso nosotros, y nos lleva tiempo. Si pides ayuda, ofrece siempre un [mre], datos de entrada y ejemplo de salida esperada para que podamos ayudarte de forma fácil y rápida!

Comment: @Benito-B Muchas gracias. Lo pongo en la pregunta, ¿no?